# Outlook VBScript Expected Statement Error

Tags: vbscript, outlook, odbc, ado

I'm new to this site.  I have searched thoroughly for an answer and cannot seem to locate an answer.  I hope one of you fine people will be able to help me....

Thank you

When I try to run my custom form with code show below, I get the following message:

```
Script Error
Expected statement
Line No:33
```

Code:

```
Function Item_Open()
    Dim LeaveItem
    Dim IO
    If not Connection_Open Then
        MsgBox("Error connecting to SI")
        LeaveItem = True
        Item_Open = False
    Else
        Item_Open = False
    End If
End Function

Function Item_Close()
    If LeaveItem = True Then
        Exit_Function
    Else
    End If
End Function

Subroutine Connection_Open()
    Dim oSI
    Set oSI = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim ostrSI
    oSI.ConnectionString = "Driver={Progress OpenEdge 10.1C  Driver};HOST=192.168.1.1;DB=kob;UID=sii;PWD=sisys1;PORT=2501;"
    oSI.Open
End Sub
```

Comment: To be clear you are running `Vbscript` not `VBA`?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Subroutine Connection_Open()
```

to

```
Sub Connection_Open()
```